# jQuery.getJSON function not work on Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

I was trying to do the project from Udacity intro to AJAX.

I made Google Streetview image appear in the background but after I was trying to add New York Times articles with `jQuery.getJSON()` method all the function get on false and lose everything I have done.

The image was disappeared and all the scripts are not functioning as well.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

```js
function loadData() {

    var $body = $('body');
    var $wikiElem = $('#wikipedia-links');
    var $nytHeaderElem = $('#nytimes-header');
    var $nytElem = $('#nytimes-articles');
    var $greeting = $('#greeting');

    // clear out old data before new request
    $wikiElem.text("");
    $nytElem.text("");

    // load streetview
 var streetStr =$('#street').val();
 var cityStr = $('#city').val();
 var address = streetStr + ',' + cityStr;
 var mapUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=' + address + ' ';
 $greeting.text('So, you want to live at' +' ' + address +  '?');
 $body.append('<img class="bgimg" src="' + mapUrl + '">');

 //NYT articles and headline
var nytUrl = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=' + cityStr + '&sort=newest&api-key=f704d0319c734128a3f7f681e32f2556';
 
 $.getJSON(nytUrl, function(data){
  $nytHeaderElem.text('New York Times Article about' +' ' + cityStr);
  
  var articles =data.response.docs;
  for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++){
   var article = articles[i];
   $nytElem.append('<li class="articles">' + '<a href="' + article.web_url+ '">' + article.headline.main + '</a>' +
      '<p>' + article.snippet + '</p>' + '</li>');
  };
 })
 
 
    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE!

    return false;
};

$('#form-container').submit(loadData);
```

```css
.bgimg {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Your moving Companion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark text-white">
    <form id="form-container" class="form-inline">
  <div class="input-group mx-2">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" for="street" id="basic-addon1">Street</span>
   </div>
   <input type="text" id="street" value>
  </div>
       <div class="input-group mx-2">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" for="city" id="basic-addon1">City</span>
   </div>
   <input type="text" id="city" value>
  </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit-btn">Submit</button> 
  </form>
 </nav>
 
  <h2 id="greeting" class="greeting text-center display-4 text-light">Where do you want to live?</h2>
  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="nytimes-container col-md-8">
    <h3 id="nytimes-header" class="display-6 text-light">New York Times Articles</h3>
    <ul id="nytimes-articles" class="lead text-white">What's going on in your new city? Enter an address and hit submit and the NY Times will tell you here!</ul>
   </div>
   
   <div class="wikipedia-container col-md-4">
    <h3 id="wikipedia-header" class="display-6 text-light">Relevant Wikipedia Links</h3>
    <ul id="wikipedia-links">Type in an address above and find relevant Wikipedia articles here!</ul>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it does not work because you (respectively bootstrap in the examples) are using the "slim" variant of jQuery (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js).

`getJson` ist not inside of this variant.

Use the "regular" minimized variant instead:
http://code.jquery.com/